# How do you put a version number into an rdlc file?

Tags: service, reporting, rdlc

I've a couple of rdlc files which I change everytime business has additional requirements. The problem is that we keep pdfs of the reports we create, and it's impossible right now to see what version of the rdlc file it was created with.

I've thought about putting a text field with "Version XX.Y" into the footer, but then I have to remember to update this when I make changes. It's not the worst solution in the world, but I'd like to hear how others handle report versioning in reporting services.

Note that I am renedering reports using local reporting, i.e. no server, so I've thought about somehow trying to display the assembly version of the application running the report. This I can control more easily with .* notation in assemblies, but I'm not sure how to have a text field which would show this.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a property containing the assembly version to the report's data source (or pass the value in some other way).

```
public string AssemblyVersion { 
    get {
        return Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(WhateverTypeThisIs)).GetName().Version;
    } 
}
```

Another option might be to use an MSBuild task to replace the version number in the .rdlc for you.  [XMLPoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff598687.aspx), for instance.

If you are using subversion, an option might be to use the [SvnInfo task from MSBuild community tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) to get the last changed rev of the report and use that number to update the XML of the rdlc file.

Comment: I was thinking about solution #2, using XMLPoke, but I couldn't find anything in the rdlc definition that looked like a version number.

Comment: I was suggesting adding/altering a text box containing some version number.